# Rails: number_field isn't showing up when outputting a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a basic form at the moment, I inserted a it has a title, body and a number_field. All three of them are working it seems, except when I go to my index to view the posts only the title and body show up, no number.

the controller:
    class AuctionsController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @auctions = Auction.all
  end

  def new
    @auctions = Auction.new
  end

  def create
    @auctions = Auction.new(auction_params)
    if @auctions.save
      redirect_to auctions_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @auctions = Auction.find(params[:id])
    @auctions.destroy
    redirect_to auctions_path
  end


  private
  def auction_params
    params.require(:auction).permit(:title, :details)
  end

end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Auction.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %> <br>
  <%= f.text_area :details %> <br>
  <%= f.number_field :price %> <br>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and my index.html.erb

```
<% @auctions.each do |auction| %>
  <%= auction.title %> <br>
  <%= auction.details %> <br>
  <%= auction.price %> <br>
  <%= link_to "Delete", auction, :method => :delete %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: what does the rendered html source look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to permit the price in your strong params helper method, try this:

```
  def auction_params
    params.require(:auction).permit(:title, :details, :price)
  end
```

Your price value was never saved, so that's why it's not showing up.
Try saving it again after these changes and it should work!

You can read more about strong parameters and how to use them properly [here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

Comment: Ah I completely forgot about that! Thank you.

Comment: No problem :) Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Definitely, it just makes me wait a few minutes before doing so. You helped me to fast! haha.